# Pivot Table : How to group by month if the dates are column headers?

Tags: google-sheets

Current table:

```
          5/4/2020  5/11/2020   5/18/2020   5/25/2020   6/1/2020
Jim          2         5            6          7           6
Jane         3         2            4          3           3
Adam         1         4            2          8           4
```

Desired table:

```
         May    June
Jim       20    6
Jane      12    3
Adam      15    4
```

Google sheet with problem: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gPSjdrF9ngaJj0KDa82qPN3iwf9Qch3jIBH0fXx7Xxo/edit#gid=1324843131

Comment: Is the existing table a pivot table or is it the structure of the source data?

Comment: Its the structure of the source data

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Do you have Microsoft Excel app? I test in Excel 365，the needs could be achieved via Multiple consolidation ranges. You may [group the Date by month manually and rename the groups' names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1mXy.gif).